Detective hunts a serial killer
Which Movie is this?
Memorable line: "That reporter wants to talk to you, she says you took her pen".
Movie opens: 2 girls go to a concert. They are picked up by the bad guy (pretending to be a band member). He locks them in seperate rooms and kills each seperately. Calls 900 number first. Uses old boxer names as aliases. Good guy collects women's numbers on matchbooks. Car chase scene where bad guys car goes into the water but a good guys body is found in the car.

 
Dead Connection (1994)

Also known as ''Final Combination''. Sex and death are the main themes
  running through this thriller. Matt Dickson is a former hockey player
  turned L.A. cop. Since his wife left him he has become a hard-drinking
  carouser. Dickson is on the trail of Welton, a psychotic boxer, using
  the names of famous fighters for his aliases has left a grisly trail
  of dead women found in cheap motels throughout the city. He is
  assisted by Catherine Briggs, a journalist, who helps him see the
  connection between these murders and similar ones in the past. But
  Catherine is not only there to help Dickson. She is also there because
  of a recent one-nighter Dickson had with her sister. (Synopsis from
  AllMovie.com)

You can watch the trailer here (alternate link). Also confirm the plot points you described here and here.
